# why SLComposeViewController not sharing text and link in Ipad?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios8.1

when I try to share text and link on Facebook using SLComposeViewController its showing in iphone but not showing in ipad.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your iPhone haven't Facebook app but iPad had it. If you have the Facebook app in your device means, then the setInitialText: function cannot works. Try your code with and without the facebook app in your device. And let me know your results.